# Firestore and Rules | Allowing/disallowing read access to post under a public/private user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**Situation**

I have the following Firestore setup

```
/posts/{id}
/posts/{id}/comments/{id}
/users/{id}/followers/{userId}
```

A user profile can either be **public** or **private**. All users can see posts by *public* users, but only users who follow *private* users can see said post, ie. they are in the owner's *followers* collection.

**Current Solution**

The post doc looks like this:

```
owner_account_visibility: public || private
ownerId: uid
```

The comment doc looks the same:

```
owner_account_visibility: public || private
ownerId: uid
```

My rules look like this

```
match /events/{eventId} {
  allow read: isValid();

  match /eventComments/{commentId} {
    allow read: isValid();
  }
}

function isValid(){
    return (resource.data.owner_account_visibility == "public" || exists(/users/$(resource.data.ownerId)/followers/request.auth.uid)))
}
```

**Problem**

I see problems/questions with this solution:

1. Problem: A user may create many posts, which in turn may have lots of comments. This means that if a user updates their account visibility, a cloud function has to update possibly thousands of post and comment documents
2. Problem: A user may load many private posts and comments, and for each one of those is a database read, which can get very expensive as the user scrolls their feed
3. Question: In the *isValid()* function, there are two conditions seperated by an OR sign (||). Does this mean that if the first condition returns true (*resource.data.owner_account_visibility == "public"*) then the function will not check the second condition (*exists(/users/$(resource.data.ownerId)/followers/request.auth.uid)*), saving me a database read? If this isn't the case, then I will waste a loooot of reads when a user loads tons of comments from a post even though it is *public*...

Does anyone have a proposed solution to this problem? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer cause seems its wong just don't implement it

Comment: Alright. no worries. I will post an answer soon as I found it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself. In short, instead of letting a user set their accounts' visibility, I let them set each post's visibility. This is simply because that is the functionality I want in my app. Now, I can simply use `resource.data.post_visibility == "public"`, avoiding the issue of having to update every post if a user changes their account's visibility. If the first condition is false, I do as I did in my current solution in the question (`exists(/users/$(resource.data.ownerId)/followers/request.auth.uid)`). Also, comments and replies to a post are opened to all authenticated users even though the post is set to private, since comments aren't necessarily the post owner's own content/sensible information